# Add new field to forum error

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify the forum on my website. What I want is just to add a new field to it. I managed to add the fields to the page where people submit their questions. This is the code for that:

```
<p>
    <?php $tags = isset( $_POST['pctest'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pctest'] ) : ''; ?>
    <input type="text" class="" name="pctest" value="<?php echo $tags ?>" >
</p>
```

From what I know I should add a code in function to make the field saved so I added this code in handle file:

```
$tags = isset( $_POST['pctest'] ) ?
esc_html( $_POST['pctest'] ): '';
```

Now to show the code in the page where people can read the question I added this code:

```
$tags = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_dwqa_question_testpc', true );
        echo 'testpc: '. $testpc;
```

That's what my page looks like, it doesn't show the text that I submit in that field, instead it shows the code!
[image]

Comment: did you forgot to open php tags `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Yup I forget it and that's embarrassing, my problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to open and close PHP tags `<?php` and `?>`.